# Does DebugActiveProcessStop close handles?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679285(v=vs.85).aspx), `ContinueDebugEvent` will close handles after `EXIT_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` and `EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`.

What happens to those handles in the following case:

```
DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(FALSE); // Keep the process running after stopping the debugger.
DebugActiveProcessStop(dwProcessId);
```

The process and threads will still be running, and [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679296(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't mention anything about handles. Can I assume that they will be closed for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, [`DebugActiveProcessStop`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/debugger.c#L521) call [`CloseAllProcessHandles`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/debugger.c#L339) before do actual stop debugging via [`DbgUiStopDebugging`](https://github.com/mirror/reactos/blob/master/reactos/dll/win32/kernel32/client/debugger.c#L533) call. the `CloseAllProcessHandles` close all opened thread and process handles. it list stored in thread `TEB` - this mean that call must be done only from the same thread which call other debug api (such `WaitForDebugEvent`). unfortunately i also not view confirmation of this in documentation, only research. this screenshot from win10

[image]

Comment: Shame it isn't documented, but this seems to answer it. Thanks!

Comment: @user1000039 - this tricks with handles, `DebugActiveProcess` implementation (which create thread in debugged process) , impossible combine wait for debug events and gui messages at once - reason why i personally not use win32 debug api but DbgUi api

Comment: @user1000039 - also in [User-Mode Debugging Internals Article](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=7) Alex Ionescu note about `CloseAllProcessHandles`. but i not msdn documentation for this

Comment: Confirmed on Win10. Easily checked with: Obtain handle during `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` event (`DebugEvent->u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess`) which is sent right after `DebugActiveProcess()` . Then later try `CloseHandle()` on it before `DebugActiveProcessStop()` and it returns OK.  But try calling it after and it returns false with "handle invalid" error. Which is how I got a clue that this was happening in the first place!

Comment: @MaximPaperno - i personally prefer use native api, `DbgUi*` for debugger. it not do not necessary things (like create new thread if attact to active process), mangage handles, etc

Comment: Interesting. I guess you're referring to using NTDLL? Seems hard to find much info on it. http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/25 and http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/DebugObject/DBG_STATE.html . In my particular use case what seems to be missing is `OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_EVENT` equivalent (just need to listen for some `OutputDebugString()` of a running 3rd-party process).

Comment: @MaximPaperno - `DbgExceptionStateChange` with exception code `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C` or `DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C` this is debug print (internally `DbgPrint`/`OutputDebugStrings`) raise this exaceptions